# C# webcam library

Tags: c#, video-streaming, webcam

I need a webcam library (for C#) so that I can implement the following things:

- show the video stream
- save the stream to a file on disk
- capture single images

I have searched for libraries and found some:

- [EasyWebcam](http://easywebcam.codeplex.com/)
- DirectShow.NET
- avicap32 using P/Invoke
- VFW

but I need some advice which one to use (maybe there are other libraries than I mentioned here).

From your experience, please recommend me a library so that I can implement the three functionalities.

Comment: I think `AForge` contains something too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to be able to choose/specify camera resolution, frame rate, pixel format, be able to work with multiple cameras, capture sound and video into one composite stream, DirectShow is the only choice.

BTW, I mean DirectShow as API, not DirectShow.Net as library. You may need to patch/fix DirectShow.Net, since it's code quality is not very good.

Comment: I am using DirectShow.NET in several apps, and hadn't any problems whatsoever.